# What in a kickstart file sets the desktop GUI as default (runlevel 5)?

Tags: linux, kickstart, rhel6

I am using Scientific Linux 6 and am installing the following desktop-related package groups:

```
@basic-desktop
@desktop-platform
@general-desktop
@x11
```

However, after installation, `/etc/inittab` still set to multi-user console runlevel (`id:2:initdefault:`).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question but I think I found something that might be it. The [xconfig option](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart#xconfig) with the `--startxonboot` parameter seems to fit perfectly.

I will test it in the morning.

Comment: Eureka! Worked. Weird that a normal install that does configure default runlevel 5 does not print out that option in the `anaconda.ks` file. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. You're using a kickstart. Can you post the full file? I've typically found that kickstart files run in `text` mode will result in a system that boots to runlevel 3. If you omit the `text` mode installation and install the requisite desktop/x11 groups, the system should default to runlevel 5.

Of course, you can add a line in the postinstall section, too...

`sed -i 's/id:2:initdefault:/id:5:initdefault:/g' /etc/inittab`

Comment: I was wondering about the `text` option as well (I am using it). According to the documentation though, that is only for the installation mode. Misdocumented perhaps? The post-install would be a last resort. The machine is at work so I will post the entire kickstart file later tomorrow morning.

Comment: Remove the `text` option and you'll get a graphical kickstart, but the installation will come up in runlevel 5.

Comment: Just tried that on a machine here at home. Did not work unfortunately. Will try again at work with that kickstart file but I'm not hopeful anymore.

Comment: I don't have a specific package/file, but why not do one install in graphical and one in text, and compare what files are different between the two?  Once you know the differences, you can use 'yum whatprovides' and hopefully find out what the missing package is.

Comment: @devicenull That was the exact process I went through and how I narrowed it down to those package groups. I submitted an answer that I will check into later on. Weird that the graphical installs I've done don't have that option in the `anaconda.ks` though. *Shrug*